# Decomposition of 3D rotations into products

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I really need help with this question, thank you in advance.

Let
$e_1=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$,
$e_2=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \in
  \mathbb{R}^3.
$
For a non-zero vector v $ \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a real number $\theta \in  \mathbb{R}$, let us denote by $R(v,\theta)$ the space rotation around the axis v with the angle $\theta$.

(1) Let u $\in  \mathbb{R}$ be a vector with |u| $= 1$. Show that there exist $ \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$R(e_2,\beta)R(e_1,\alpha)u=e_1.$$

Comment: Thinking to $\alpha$ = latitude and $\beta$=(a kind of) longitude should help you...

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I'll work on it!

Comment: In fact, my answer includes this strong analogy with longitude and latitude because it retrieves a form of spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to Question (1):

Relationship

$$R(e_2,\beta)R(e_1,\alpha)u=e_1$$

can be written into an equivalent form:

$$u=\underbrace{R(e_1,\alpha)^{-1}}_{R_1}\underbrace{R(e_2,\beta)^{-1}}_{R_2}e_1$$

which can be transformed into:

$$\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos(\alpha)&\sin(\alpha)\\0&-\sin(\alpha)&\cos(\alpha)\end{pmatrix}}_{R_1}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\beta)&0&\sin(\beta)\\0&1&0\\-\sin(\beta)&0&\cos(\beta)\end{pmatrix}}_{R_2}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\beta)\\ -\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\\-\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\end{pmatrix}$$

(do you recognize spherical coordinates, but not in the usual order ? In fact $\beta$ can be at once recognized as the classical longitude).

As coordinate $|u|=1 \implies u_1 \in (-1,1)$, we can deduce that :

$$\beta = \operatorname{acos}u_1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \alpha=\operatorname{atan}\tfrac{u_2}{u_3}$$

with a particular case for the forbidden value $u_3=0$ for which $\alpha=\pi/2.$

Up to you for the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply on the left with $R(e_1, \gamma)$, and you can get any rotation via Euler decomposition, including those that send $u$ to $e_1$.